# Object Disappear if Children Overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a div with children div.  I was wondering if there was a property in CSS that would make a whole object disappear if any of its children where overflowing?  Here is my div code if that would be useful at all

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <a class="pod_full" href="/pod.php?id=1337">
        <img class="pod_thumb" src="http://placehold.it/73x73" />
        <div class="pod_info">
           Woah
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Javascript by detecting if the offset of the child is greater than the offset of the parent.

See:

http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/detecting-overflow-with-javascript-css-61592.html

Comment: have tired overflow:hidden and give a height to the parent div